# Randomizar de acordo com um botão de rádio

Tags: php

Quero fazer o uso dos "Radio Buttons", do HTML mas não sei como usá-los. Como fazê-los eu sei, mas preciso de algo como isso:

Se eu usar a opção um, gerar uma palavra aleatória sendo elas Língua, Linguagem.

Se eu usar a opção dois, gerar uma palavra aleatória sendo elas Idioma, Dialeto.

Eu sei gerar uma palavra entre aleatórias com o PHP, preciso saber como "distribuir" as duas.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SO em português. Tente explicar melhor sua necessidade, inclusive nos dizendo o que já tem. Considere fazer o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e também [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Já tentou usar Jquery pra ficar dinâmico(quando escolher um faz a ação A quando escolher o outro faz a ação B)

Comment: @ThallesDaniel Como faço isso? Sou zerado em Javascript e jquery

Comment: Já que vc está do "0" veja um exemplo que fiz pra vc ter uma ideia do que vc pode fazer com jquery

Comment: Como está seu código pra gerar as palavras aleatórias

Answer (score 2):

Veja assim:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radioA').click(function() {
    var data = 'id=aleaa';
    $.get('aleatoria.php', data, function(response){
      $('#dv').html(response);
    });
  });
  $('#radioB').click(function() {
    var data = 'id=aleab';
    $.get('aleatoria.php', data, function(response){
      $('#dv').html(response);
    });
  });
});
</script>

<div id="dv"></div><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="aleatoria" id="radioA"> aleatório A<br>

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="aleatoria" id="radioB"> aleatório B<br>
<!--<button id="buton">Click</button>-->

</body>
```

e crie um arquivo aleatoria.php assim:

```
<?php
    if($_GET["id"] == "aleaa")
    {
    $palavras = array('Língua','Linguagem'); 
    $aleatorio = rand(0,1); 
    echo $palavras[$aleatorio];
    } 
    elseif($_GET["id"] == "aleab")
    {
    $palavras = array('Idioma','Dialeto'); 
    $aleatorio = rand(0,1); 
    echo $palavras[$aleatorio];
    }
 ?>
```

O jquery faz um GET no arquivo aleatoria.php se o parâmetro(?id=alea) tiver correto ele pega a palavra aleatória que gerou. Se foi satisfatórias as repostas peço que pontue :)

Comment: Isso é o que eu sei fazer amigo. Quero botões de rádio, um randomiza uma coisa e outro outra

Comment: se vc sabe fazer isso então basta trocar o botão pelo radio veja.

Comment: Atualizei o código do jeito que vc quer um radioA faz um aleatório de língua e linguagem e o radioB faz de Idioma e Dialeto. O código está pronto.